# Run `git clone` with custom DNS?

Tags: linux, git, azure, amazon-web-services, dns

**TLDR:** Is there a way to run a `git clone [url]` with the URL being temporarily hard coded for the git command only?

I am running into a scenario where a hosted environment in the cloud (Azure, AWS, etc) can be burned down and then recreated using same name in short window of time (say within 10 minutes). This results in re-use of the DNS name (ie mycoolwebsite.azurewebsites.com).

Inevitably a command to do a git clone/git push pointed at that DNS name results in failure since the DNS entry that is cached on the machine is now stale since the recreated environment may likely live behind a different external IP.

Through the cloud hosting providers tooling I can query the external IP and do a injection/ejection into `/etc/hosts`. This has been a functioning workaround but its a "bad idea" for many reasons. I cannot easily point to the IP as the endpoint as the server won't respond to naked IPs, only hostnames (from what I can gather).

I imagine this has been encountered by numerous folks turning up and burning down dev instances in the cloud - is there a better way to handle what is basically a DNS caching issue?

Comment: In AWS you can request an elastic IP that you map to the EC2 instance.  When the EC2 instance changes you just re-map the elastic IP to the new instance, which is much faster than a DNS change.  I imagine Azure has similar functionality.

Comment: @david25272 indeed, this functionality might be solution, but it requires elastic IP which when doing something like ephemeral test instances, it decreases in value. Hoping to have something that could be done on the machine level to run a command (namely `git`) with a specific DNS modification. I tried one other trick, but it didn't seem that git used that DNS lookup method. I can't find the exact link though at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I was really looking to do was:** Pin a request to an IP address.

This ability was added git in ~2022, 5+ years after question asked. Ref: [[1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/511cfd3bffa685fda0e7c25bfa08082aa0de3a30)] [[2](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html)]

**Solution:**

```
git -c http.curloptResolve="+github.com:443:192.30.255.112" clone https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo
```

- `http.curloptResolve`: Provides cURL a custom host name to IP address DNS entry
- `+github.com:443:192.30.255.112`: [+]HOST:PORT:ADDRESS[,ADDRESS]

  - The `+` makes the DNS entry not permanent
- Similar/same [concept exists in `cURL`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) via command line flag `--resolve`.

---

To test/validate, enabled verbose git logging:

> $env:GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1; $env:GIT_TRACE=1; $env:GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1;
> git -c http.curloptResolve="+github.com:443:192.30.255.112" clone
> https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo

Answer (score 1):

@david said, In AWS, you could select elastic IP.  On Azure, you could associate [static Public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal) to a VM.

According to your scenario, you could unmap the IP to your original VM and associate the IP to your new VM. The IP address will not change.

Update:

You could use [Azure Cli 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to disassociate Public IP or associate Public IP to a VM. You could refer to the example below:

```
##chang publci from dynamic to Static
az network public-ip update -g shuitest -n shui-ip --allocation-method Static
##disassoicat PublicIP from a VM
az network nic ip-config update --resource-group shuitest --nic-name shui7 --name ipconfig1 --public-ip ""
##add the Publci IP to new VM
az network nic ip-config update --resource-group shuitest --nic-name shui7 --name ipconfig1 --public-ip "shui-ip"
```

You could use `-h` to get help.

```
[root@localhost .ssh]# az network nic ip-config update -h

Command
    az network nic ip-config update: Update an IP configuration.
```

Comment: I'll upvote this but I am hoping for something a little less cludgy for dealing with say 100+ ephemeral test instances.

Comment: @PotatoFarmer You could upvote if you have 15 rep. If you have multiple VMs, you could create a Powershell script to do it.

Comment: Upvoted, as it is relevant as a workaround specifically for Azure. However I would like the answer to either be a direct solution of running `git clone {url}` with a custom temporary dns for that `{url}`. Alternatively you mention a possible powershell/az-cli script that could achieve something to that effect in Azure? Please share if time allows and I would consider that as a possible answer.